# How to interpret when the test error is low when model memorizes training data

Tags: machine-learning

Has anyone experienced that the regression model output really high score even on test set when it just purely memorized the  training data (0% error)? How would you interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the data has very low noise compared to noise. If you do not think the signal is that strong, up on my experience, too small test errors may come from some bugs in the code, mainly in the feature engineering parts or data splitting part.